# ASCX files

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application project that contains only .ascx files. I build it to create a dll and then reference the dll from another web app project. Do I need to copy over the .ascx files over the the site as well. If i need to copy them over, where do i need to place them?

**EDIT: I was able to fix the cause of this problem.**

The web application containing the ascx files was a website project that was converted to a web application. During this conversion some namespaces got mangled and as a result we had namespace like: SmartDev.SmartDev instead of just SmartDev.

I had to modify the tag prefix entry in the web.config file to use "SmartDev.SmartDev" and it worked. I had to go to every single location in html and change the modified class file names though...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll need the .ascx files.  Place them in the directory structure somewhere logical that you can reference from wherever you are instantiating the controls.

Comment: You could use fully qualified names.